# Adding a multiselect to my form as a custom form field with SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sonata-admin

I have been searching for a way to add a custom multiselect to my create/edit form in the sonata bundle.
The field should looks like this:
[image]

In the documentation (http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html) they speak of the addType function. Although this function is not present.

Can someone tell me **how to add a custom field to my form?**
And provide a more detailed explanation on **how to use templates, insert data on edit and get the data on save of the enitity.**
Thanks for the help

Comment: The lastest version of sonata admin has a better UI for the type of render you want.

Comment: That sounds great, I did not notise that. Whats the type calle then?

Comment: I am currently running sonata admin bundle 2.2.7

Comment: 2.2.7 is currently the lastest. If your elements are entities just try formMapper->add('entity', null, array('multiple'=>true, 'expanded'=>true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set **mapped=false**. like.

```
    $formMapper
    ->add('name',null,array('label'=>'Namer'))
            ->add('customFiled',null,array('required'=>false,'mapped'=>false))//Costom fields
    ->end();
```